# What is the time complexity in solving a polynomial equation of degree N in one variable?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

How easy/difficult(in terms of big-O) is it to solve polynomial equations of high degrees of N?

Do apps like Desmos actually solve equations to get roots or do they approximate roots by iterating through a range of values for x?

What mechanisms are at play in solving a univariate polynomial equation algorithmically?

Comment: What do you mean by *solving*? How is the solution represented?

Comment: By "solving" I mean obtaining a list of all its real roots

Comment: How are the solutions represented? Even assuming that the coefficients are integers, the solutions need not be rational. Perhaps you want, given some $\epsilon > 0$, a list of all roots up to error $\epsilon$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Roots_of_polynomials, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials

Comment: @D.W. Thanks! That helped :)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus In my particular case, I'm looking at polynomials with integral (or worst case, non-integral, rational) roots. I'm trying to encrypt strings by assigning polynomial equations with roots equal to the positional occurrences of these characters. So, a string made up with letters from the alphabet would be encrypted into 26 equations of varying degrees. The essence of my question is to find out if this is a competent encryption technique.

Comment: If you invent a new cryptographic scheme, it is most likely not secure.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity doesn't just depend on N. It's possible that due to the coefficients, you have to evaluate the polynomial with very high precision to determine whether some minimum of the polynomial near a point x has a value >0, =0 or <0, and you need to know this to know the number of roots near to x (0, 1, or 2).